# Datatable, table overlapped when using fixed column

Tags: javascript, datatable

Base on the code I use below, my table is messed up when using fixed column. It seems that my table is overlapped at the first 3 left column. I suspect that scrollX is making the problem because the table looks perfectly fine without it.

Any ideas why this happen and how to solve it?

[image]

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    scrollY:        "300px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
    fixedColumns:   {
        leftColumns:3
    }
} );
```

```html
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" style="width:100%">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>First name</th>
             <th>Last name</th>
             <th>Position</th>
             <th>Office</th>
             <th>Age</th>
             <th>Start date</th>
             <th>Salary</th>
             <th>Extn.</th>
             <th>E-mail</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>Tiger</td>
             <td>Nixon</td>
             <td>System Architect</td>
             <td>Edinburgh</td>
             <td>61</td>
             <td>2011/04/25</td>
             <td>$320,800</td>
             <td>5421</td>
             <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Garrett</td>
             <td>Winters</td>
             <td>Accountant</td>
             <td>Tokyo</td>
             <td>63</td>
             <td>2011/07/25</td>
             <td>$170,750</td>
             <td>8422</td>
             <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Ashton</td>
             <td>Cox</td>
             <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
             <td>San Francisco</td>
             <td>66</td>
             <td>2009/01/12</td>
             <td>$86,000</td>
             <td>1562</td>
             <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Cedric</td>
             <td>Kelly</td>
             <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
             <td>Edinburgh</td>
             <td>22</td>
             <td>2012/03/29</td>
             <td>$433,060</td>
             <td>6224</td>
             <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Is the question about jQuery? You should tag it right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read dataTable documentation properly and include all css & js external script in your code

Your problem is missing some external script 
[Here is the working solution](https://codepen.io/anandhukrishnavr/pen/JVbwVV)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 2
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
/* Ensure that the demo table scrolls */
    th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
    div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.csshttps://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett</td>
            <td>Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
            <td>8422</td>
            <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton</td>
            <td>Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
            <td>1562</td>
            <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric</td>
            <td>Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
            <td>6224</td>
            <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Include**

[dataTables.min.css](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css)

[fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css](https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css)

[jquery.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js)

[jquery.dataTables.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)

[dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js](https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js)

Comment: by looking at the codepen you provided, the table still overlapped

Comment: overlapped means ? compare [dataTable](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/two_columns.html) v/s [codepen](https://codepen.io/anandhukrishnavr/pen/JVbwVV)  v/s your gif

Comment: the codepen output is same as you can see on my gif, by the way, i already followed everything what the datatable stated by importing all the cdn

Comment: codepen answer [updated](https://codepen.io/anandhukrishnavr/pen/JVbwVV)

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: it was a external style sheet missing!please accept if answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed by removing table-checkable class

```
<table  class="table table-hover full-width" ></table>
```

> table-checkable